# function max_and_min(t1, t2) that takes in two tuples

Tags: python, max, min, assertion

> Write the function max_and_min(t1, t2) that takes in two tuples, computes the element-wise sums, and returns a tuple containing the maximum and minimum across all the sums. You may assume the tuples are the same length.

Bottom is my code, but it keep shows this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/codio/workspace/.guides/secure/test_max_and_min.py", line 8, in test_basic
    self.assertEqual(max_and_min((2, 3), (9, 1)), (11, 4))
AssertionError: Tuples differ: (12, 3) != (11, 4)

First differing element 0:
12
11

- (12, 3)
+ (11, 4)
```

```
def max_and_min(t1, t2):
  t3 =[]
  res =[]

  t = ()
  l1=list(t1)
  l2=list(t2)

  for i in range (len(l1)):
    for j in range(len(l2)):
      t3.append(l1[i]+l2[j])
  res.append(max(t3))
  res.append(min(t3))
  t=tuple(res)

  return t
```

Comment: Write out what your two `for` loops are doing on paper, and you'll probably see the mistake.

Comment: Element-wise sum doesn't mean cross product sum.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is simply:

```
def max_and_min(t1, t2):
    sums = [sum(elems) for elems in zip(t1, t2)]
    return max(sums), min(sums)
```

`sums` is the element-wise sums, and the desired answer is the `max` and `min` of those.

Comment: And the most important part is using `zip`.